# How to optimize a query using multiple where conditions and a table with millions of observations

Tags: sql-server, optimization, where-clause

I am using the below query that is taking hours to run. Is there some way to optimize this query to make it run faster?

**Structure of DF:**

| PT_ID | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Code5 | Code6 | dx_code | insurance_clm_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**#DX Size:** 384 rows of data

Note: df is a table with a large number (5+ million) observations

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT pt_ID
INTO #pt_list
FROM df
WHERE ((Code1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dx)
            OR Code2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dx)
            OR Code3 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dx)
            OR Code4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dx)
            OR Code5 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dx)
            OR Code6 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dx)
            )
OR dx_code IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM #dxWHERE [Code Description] IN ('Emergency')))
AND insurance_clm_date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2022-11-15'
```

**CREATE TABLE DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE #df
(pt_id    VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 Code1 VARCHAR(7) NULL, 
 Code2     VARCHAR(7) NULL, 
 Code3  VARCHAR(7) NULL, 
 Code4      VARCHAR(7) NULL,
 Code5      VARCHAR(7) NULL, 
 Code6      VARCHAR(7) NULL,
 dx_code      VARCHAR(5) NULL,
 insurance_clm_date      DATE NULL
);
```

**DF Indexes:**

insurance_clm_date(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
PT_ID(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
dx_code(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)

Any tips would be appreciated. Would a pivot of table df so that Codes1-4 are all under a code column prior to this query be helpful?

Comment: Add the indexes (including constraints) you currently have on the `df` table to your question.

Comment: Also, consider creating a non-clustered columnstore index on df table `pt_ID`, `[Code Description]`, `insurance_clm_date`, and all code columns.

Comment: 5 million rows really isn't very big and certainly shouldn't be "taking hours to run" - what does the execution plan look like? and how many rows in `#dx`?

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added the columns in DF. Is that what you meant by indexes?

Comment: @MartinSmith I have added the number of rows in #dx as well

Comment: No, I mean the indexes. Include the CREATE TABLE DDL and indexes.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I apologize for the delay and the confusion. New to SQL and had to do some research about indexes and the CREATE TABLE DDL. I have added what I think you are looking for. Please let me know if it is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Would a pivot of table df so that Codes1-4 are all under a code column prior to this query be helpful?

Only if you materialized the results to a table so they're already stored in that format. Then you can create an index on that single column.

Your issue appears to be lack of indexes covering the `Code` columns. You've provided the names of your indexes (not their definitions, which you can obtain by right clicking on them and generating the `CREATE` scripts for), so this is slightly a guess, but seems based on the names and the number of them compared to the number of `Code` columns, that this is highly likely your root problem.

By not having indexes covering your `Code` columns, the entire table needs to be scanned, probably once for each `Code` column. That's millions of rows, multiple times.

If you could provide your [execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/execution-plans?view=sql-server-ver16) (even the estimated) via [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) then we may be able to recommend an indexing strategy. If you wanted to go the extra mile, you can download Brent Ozar's [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/), run `sp_BlitzWho @GetLiveQueryPlan = 1` while your query is running, and you'll get a more accurate estimated plan that you can provide.